# composer playground add participants by default

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

is there any option, that I can add e.g. 100 participants by default to my network? Don't want to click the "add participant" 100 times for realising this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Transaction that creates many Assets and Participants - the **Vehicle-Lifecycle-Network** and **Animal-Tracking-Network** samples in Playground both have `setupDemo` transactions that you could examine.

Alternatively you could start a REST server for your network (assuming you have a real Fabric to deploy the network to) `composer-rest-server` and the paste in an Array of JSON objects on the POST request for your Participant type. E.g. for the tutorial network:

```
[
{
"$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Trader",
"tradeId": "t01",
"firstName": "mark",
"lastName": "t"
},
{
"$class": "org.acme.mynetwork.Trader",
"tradeId": "t02",
"firstName": "huw",
"lastName": "t"
}]
```

Or you could use [Node RED](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-composer) to set up a workflow to import files into your Fabric.